# Finding the Max and min of $2x^3-3y^2-2x+1/2$ on the disk $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: calculus

I have found the critical point (1/2,0) i also know from the Hessian that it is a saddle point, but what can is say about the Max an min on the boundary does anyone have a method for me?

Comment: on the boundary x^2+y^2 = 1

Comment: set $$y^2=1-x^2$$ in your equation